# AFNetworking 2.0: credentials not sent to authentication within 30 seconds of previous request

Tags: ios, authentication, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation

I am using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to get some data from our server. The server uses Basic authentication.

When the user logs into our app I set the credentials like this:

```
manager.credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

And then I make a request like this:

```
[manager GET:address parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

When I make the request the method `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` gets called (the method is implemented in `AFURLConnectionOperation`).

When the user logs out of the app and logs in again I set the credentials again from the user input. However, if this happens within 30 seconds of the previous successful request the credentials are not sent to authentication (`connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` is not called). This means that the user can log out and then apparently log in even if the new credentials are incorrect since they are never checked.

If I wait at least 30 seconds there doesn't seem to be an issue (i.e. the credentials are checked and I get a 401 error).

Do I need to clear the credentials somehow when the user is logging out or am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: I just had the same exact problem, did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found out that there's a connection to AFNetworking's AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's method [shouldUseCredentialStorage](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/shouldUseCredentialStorage) which defaults to `YES`.
And since I didn't find a way to clear the credentials on logout, what I do now is just disable the `credentialStorage` altogether like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.shouldUseCredentialStorage = NO;
```

Not sure if that's the best possible solution but works for me.